# Why is my color change script not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 files for a small color changing website project I am working on. I have an index.html file, index.css file, and colorScript.js file. What I can't figure out is why the script won't run and change the box from white to red. I have provided the code of each file and need help figuring out why it either doesn't work or won't connect.

```js
var value = false;

function setColor(color) {
  var property = document.getElementById(color);
  if (value == false) {
    property.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
    value = true;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: rgb(44, 44, 44);
    max-width: 1920px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.side1 {
    background-color: lightskyblue;
    border: 5px solid black;
    width: 10%;
    height: 90vh;
    position: absolute;
    left: 23%;
}

.middle {
    margin: auto;
    background-color: lightseagreen;
    border: 5px solid black;
    width: 34%;
    height: 90vh;
    text-align: center;
}

.title {
    color: white;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: white;
    text-decoration-thickness: 2px;
    text-underline-offset: 5px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
    padding-top: 10%;
}

.description {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 41.5%;
    width: 300px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0.4px;
    text-wrap: normal;
}

.color {
    margin: 182px auto;
    background-color: white;
    width: 400px;
    height: 195px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.header {
    margin: -60px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
}

.side2 {
    background-color: lightskyblue;
    border: 5px solid black;
    width: 10%;
    height: 90vh;
    position: absolute;
    left: 67%;
}

.but1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 125px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 13.5%;
    top: 35%;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

.but1:hover {
    background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
}

.but2 {
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 125px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 13.5%;
    top: 35%;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

.but2:hover {
    background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
  <section>
    <div class="side1">
      <button type="button" class="but1" onclick="setColor('color')">&lt;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="side2">
      <button type="button" class="but2">&gt;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
      <i><header class="title">Color Change Test</header></i>
      <p class="description">This color changing project was made so I can experiment with javascript</p>
      <div class="color">
        <p class="header">Color Box</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

I have read each line carefully and asked my coworkers (We are still in college, we are not professional. We don't know anything) to read through my code and they said that it should work theoretically.

Comment: You're calling `getElementById()` with 'color', but your `div` has no such ID; it's its _class_ that is named 'color'... take a look at `querySelector()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

- You use [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) but you don't have an ID set on your `<div>` but instead a class of `color` so `undefined` i. e. no element will be returned. Instead you need to select the element with the class `color` (or switch to an ID) and use e.g. [`querySelector(".color")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to get the element
- The parameter of your function is called `color` but you don't pass it a color but an ID instead, which makes no sense. You should really pass a color here, since that is what you want to customize, the ID (or class => see first issue) will stay the same, so there is no point to make that configurable here
- You shouldn't really be using `==` in JavaScript to compare values since this can cause unexpected results if you don't really know what you are doing due to [type coercion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion). Be explicit and strict with what you expect i. e. use `===` or [`!==`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_inequality) for comparisons where possible. You actually wanna check if an element was found which you do with `value !== undefined`
- Try to avoid `var` to declare variables since this makes the variables global. You should try to keep state local and [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object#Immutable_variables) if possible so it's much better to use [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) or [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) (see also [MDN Docs - Scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope)).
- Last but not least, you can see that on different screen sizes the layout doesn't look great. You can fix that too with a bit more effort. That's however not the scope of this answer. But if you're interested have a look at [web.dev - Learning Responsive Design](https://web.dev/learn/design?hl=en)

Here your sample with all of the above tips (except the last) applied:'

> I've modified the behavior a bit, to have some interacivity. If you press left, the color changes to red, if you press right, the color changes to green due to the parameters changes I've made (see 2nd issue)

```js
let value = false;

function setColor(color) {
  const property = document.querySelector(".color");
  if (value !== undefined) {
    property.style.backgroundColor = color;
    value = true;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: rgb(44, 44, 44);
    max-width: 1920px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.side1 {
    background-color: lightskyblue;
    border: 5px solid black;
    width: 10%;
    height: 90vh;
    position: absolute;
    left: 23%;
}

.middle {
    margin: auto;
    background-color: lightseagreen;
    border: 5px solid black;
    width: 34%;
    height: 90vh;
    text-align: center;
}

.title {
    color: white;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: white;
    text-decoration-thickness: 2px;
    text-underline-offset: 5px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
    padding-top: 10%;
}

.description {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 41.5%;
    width: 300px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0.4px;
    text-wrap: normal;
}

.color {
    margin: 182px auto;
    background-color: white;
    width: 400px;
    height: 195px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.header {
    margin: -60px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
}

.side2 {
    background-color: lightskyblue;
    border: 5px solid black;
    width: 10%;
    height: 90vh;
    position: absolute;
    left: 67%;
}

.but1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 125px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 13.5%;
    top: 35%;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

.but1:hover {
    background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
}

.but2 {
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 125px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 13.5%;
    top: 35%;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

.but2:hover {
    background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
  <section>
    <div class="side1">
      <button type="button" class="but1" onclick="setColor('red')">&lt;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="side2">
      <button type="button" class="but2" onclick="setColor('green')">&gt;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
      <i><header class="title">Color Change Test</header></i>
      <p class="description">This color changing project was made so I can experiment with javascript</p>
      <div class="color">
        <p class="header">Color Box</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: This is my first time messing with javascript and this helps me massively. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

because your

```
var property = document.getElementById("color");
```

color !== "color", should be a string

and add id="color"

```
<div class="color" id="color">
```

Comment: How do you know it should be a string? `color` is a parameter. Maybe not the best idea of naming a parameter, but functionality wise it'll work just fine as long as the correct id is being sent towards the function.

Comment: I see what I did, thank you